# Explaining proposition 22 on pg.25 in Halsey Royden.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The proposition is given below:

> [image]

But I do not understand it, could anyone give me a numerical example of it so that I can feel it more?

Thanks!

Comment: The open sets in the topology induced by the topology of $\mathbf R$ on $E$ have precisely the form $E\cap \mathcal U$, where $\mathcal U$ is an open set of $\mathbf R$. So this means the inverse image by $f$ of any open set set $\mathcal O$ of $\mathbf R$ is an open set of $E$ for the induced topology, which is the most general definition of continuity.

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $E = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, but is not the restriction of a continuous function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, for example.